# grabbing text between two elements in nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

```
<body>
 <div>some text</div>
 I NEED THIS TEXT ONLY
 <div>some text</div>
 more text here
 <div>some text</div>
 one more text here
 <div>some text</div>
</body>
```

How?

Answer (score 5):

**Use**:

```
/*/div[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

This selects the first text-node sibling of the first `div` child of the top element of the document.

Answer (score 0):

this returns the first text node within `body` between two `div` elements:

```
/body/text()[
     ./preceding::element()[1][local-name()="div"] and 
     ./following::element()[1][local-name()="div"]
][1]
```

should return

```
I NEED THIS TEXT ONLY
```

Comment: No, i need exacly get text between two divs.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath 1.0:

```
/body/text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::div]]
            [following-sibling::*[1][self::div]][1]
```

Also:

```
/body/text()[normalize-space()][1]
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have nokogiri, but here's an alternative using just basic string manipulation.

```
html=<<EOF
<body>
 <div>some text</div>
 I NEED THIS TEXT ONLY
 <div>some text</div>
 more text here
 <div>some text</div>
 one more text here
 <div>some text</div>
</body>
EOF
p html.split(/<\/*body>/)[1].split(/<\/div>/)[1].split(/<div>/)[0]
```

Comment: O.M.G., if this was a Perl question lightning would have struck. For anything but the most trivial task string manipulation and/or its cousin REGEX will fail badly. For fun search for perl, regex and parsing html.

Comment: OP's requirement is trivial. For me, there's no reason to use nokogiri or some other parsing tool.

Comment: the vast majority of times, I need a screen scraper to work exactly one time. Messing around figuring out how to address things with xpath instead of using split & regex is a criminal waste of my clients money.