# Getting Data Between Elements in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to get the text between two elements in nokogiri and pair the data with the text in the element in front of it.

```
html  = 
"<website>
    <maindeck>
        1<card>Blood Crypt</card>
        2<card>Temple Garden</card>
    </maindeck>
    <maindeck>
        3<card>Angel of Serenity</card>
        4<card>Forest</card>
    </maindeck>
</website>"
```

I want to end up with an array like this

```
#=> [[1,"Blood Crypt"],[2,"Temple Garden"]]
```

A previous example provided this as an answer, but I'm unsure of what it does/ how to use it.

```
/*/div[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Original link : [grabbing text between two elements in nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911656/grabbing-text-between-two-elements-in-nokogiri)

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Don't expect someone to write the entire code for you, most probably no one will. Show the community the effort you have put in by means of code you've got so far and someone will gladly help if you are stuck.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first post, so I was unsure of the protocol. I had a look at the link you provided, and was in the middle of adding more to my original post.

Comment: I think the criteria was pretty clear (i.e. the desired result), which is not the case in many SO questions. For this type of question, I consider that to be the minimum requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath('//maindeck[1]/text()').map { |n| [n.text.to_i, n.next.text] }
#=> [[1, "Blood Crypt"], [2, "Temple Garden"]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much!
It was the /text() I wasn't sure about.

Comment: Would you happen to know how xpath needs to be formatted for elements with class definitions.

eg <div class="maindeck>1<a class="card">Blood Crypt</a></div>

I tried //div.maindeck/a.card

Comment: Yep, select by class with e.g. `div[@class="myclass"]`.

Comment: p.s. be careful with that class-matcher, it is an *exact* matcher so if you have `<div class="myclass anotherclass"></div>` it won't match because it sees the class as `"myclass anotherclass"`. If you want to match one class out of many, use `div[contains(@class,"myclass")]`.

Comment: That's actually a good reason to use css selectors instead of xpath. `div.myclass` will match in your example and in a much simpler way.

Comment: Xpath isn't meant to be intuitive. It's meant for a machines. That's why humans should use css.

Comment: Well, we could discuss this forever. Call me a machine, but I like the consistency of its syntax.